# Android animate drawing in a custom ImageView

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I am trying to create a custom image view that accepts an array of points and draws them on the image one after the other (not all at once)

I did the following implementation which draws all circles at once.

```
public class CustomImageView extends ImageView {

    private static final int RADIUS = 20;

    private List<Point> points = new ArrayList<>();
    private Paint paint;

    public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);

        points.add(new Point(100, 100));
        points.add(new Point(200, 200));
        points.add(new Point(300, 300));
        points.add(new Point(400, 400));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        if (!points.isEmpty()) {

            for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
                Point point = points.get(i);
                canvas.drawCircle(point.x, point.y, RADIUS, paint);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can i draw the above dummy points on the image one after the other with a small delay?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a way to do it with a `ValueAnimator`.

The thing to keep in mind is that `onDraw()` can be called at any time for a lot of different reasons, so you want to have some state that tells you how to draw the thing right *now*.  In our case, it will be `mNumCirclesToDraw`.  That state is always checked in `onDraw()`.

The next part to get this working is to create a `ValueAnimator` that will update this state at the right time then call `invalidate()` to force a redraw.

Here is an example:

```
public class CustomImageView extends ImageView implements ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener {

    private static final int RADIUS = 20;

    private List<Point> points = new ArrayList<>();
    private Paint paint;

    private ValueAnimator mValueAnimator;

    private int mNumCirclesToDraw = 0;

    public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);

        points.add(new Point(100, 100));
        points.add(new Point(200, 200));
        points.add(new Point(300, 300));
        points.add(new Point(400, 400));

        setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mValueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, points.size());
                mValueAnimator.setDuration(500 * points.size());
                mValueAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
                mValueAnimator.addUpdateListener(CustomImageView.this);
                mValueAnimator.start();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        int val = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
        if (val != mNumCirclesToDraw) {
            mNumCirclesToDraw = val;
            invalidate();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        if (!points.isEmpty()) {

            for (int i = 0; i < mNumCirclesToDraw; i++) {
                Point point = points.get(i);
                canvas.drawCircle(point.x, point.y, RADIUS, paint);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Try this in your project.  Click on the `CustomImageView` to kick off the animation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it did the job. need to understand more custom drawing so i can tweak it as needed.